# What is the original paper using Extended Kalman Filter for joint state and parameter estimation

Tags: control-engineering, engineering-history, kalman-filters

The title says it all.

I would like to know which was the first paper to apply the Extended Kalman Filter to jointly estimate the state plus some parameter of the system.
(by extending the system state to include the unknown parameter as an extra state component)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So go to Elsevier or equivalent and do a search - papers tend to have published dates.

Comment: Hi @SolarMike! You certainly don't think creating an account in this platform was the first way I thought of to search for the answer...
I really can't find the original paper to come up with the idea. If you think it is worthy I can post the older reference I found using this technique. Thanks

Comment: @GFrazao i do think your first attempt was to come here and ask people to do your search for you, otherwise i fail to understand why our google-fu should be better than yours.